# AngularJS-undefined value radio button

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem in retrieving the value of the radio button with angularJS.

I have done displaying roles of users in the form of radio buttons to send IdRole of each role selected by the administrator to the angularJS function as it is shown in this:

**html code**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.roleUser.$touched && myForm.roleUser.$error.required }">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Role of User*:</label>  
  <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" ng-repeat="roles in ListRolesUsers">
    <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio1" name="roleUser" ng-model="roleUser" value="{{roles.idRole}}">
    <label for="inlineRadio1"> <strong> {{roles.idRole}} // {{roles.nomRole}}</strong> </label>
  </div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
var app = angular.module('Mainapp', ['ngRoute','file model','ui.bootstrap','ngMessages']);
app.controller("Users"['$scope','fileUpload','$http','$window', function($scope,fileUpload,$http,$window){
  $scope.AddUsers = function() {
    console.log("id role of user: "+$scope.roleUser); // id role of user: undefined
  }
}
```

After a test always **idRole is undefined** I do not know why.

The list of roles is displayed in the browser:

```
Role of User*:

    1 // Admin

    2 // SuperUsers

    3 // SimpleUsers
```

format of **ListRolesUsers**:

```
[{"idRole":1,"nomRole":"Admin","authority":"Admin"},
{"idRole":2,"nomRole":"SuperUsers","authority":"SuperUsers"},{"idRole":3,"nomRole":"SimpleUsers","authority":"SimpleUsers"}]
```

**The list of roles is retrieved from the database**

How to ensure that the value of the radio button?

Comment: You should use ng-value="..." instead of value="{{...}}". Can you please provider a plunkr or jsfiddle with your problem ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir @Julien, I used the **ng-value="roles.idRole"** attribute as you said but always the value is undefined.
The list of roles is retrieved from the database

Comment: Would need to see the format of your `ListRolesUsers` data.

Comment: [{"idRole":1,"nomRole":"Admin","authority":"Admin"},{"idRole":2,"nomRole":"SuperUsers","authority":"SuperUsers"},{"idRole":3,"nomRole":"SimpleUsers","authority":"SimpleUsers"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to have a classic scope issue.
Your ngRepeat is creating a new scope for each item. And, when you set a ngModel like you did, you will affect it to your ngRepeat-item scope.

To avoid it, two solutions :

### use a named controller

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="Users as $ctrl" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.roleUser.$touched && myForm.roleUser.$error.required }">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Role of User*:</label>  
  <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" ng-repeat="roles in $ctrl.ListRolesUsers">
    <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio1" name="roleUser" ng-model="$ctrl.roleUser" ng-value="roles.idRole">
    <label for="inlineRadio1"> <strong> {{roles.idRole}} // {{roles.nomRole}}</strong> </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('Mainapp', ['ngRoute','file model','ui.bootstrap','ngMessages']);
app.controller("Users"['$scope','fileUpload','$http','$window', function($scope,fileUpload,$http,$window){
  var vm = this;

  $scope.AddUsers = function() {
    console.log("id role of user: "+vm.roleUser); // id role of user: undefined
  }
}
```

### Use an object in your ngModel

**Html**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.roleUser.$touched && myForm.roleUser.$error.required }">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Role of User*:</label>  
  <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" ng-repeat="roles in ListRolesUsers">
    <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio1" name="roleUser" ng-model="userSelection.roleUser" ng-value="roles.idRole">
    <label for="inlineRadio1"> <strong> {{roles.idRole}} // {{roles.nomRole}}</strong> </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('Mainapp', ['ngRoute','file model','ui.bootstrap','ngMessages']);
app.controller("Users"['$scope','fileUpload','$http','$window', function($scope,fileUpload,$http,$window){
  $scope.userSelection = {};
  $scope.AddUsers = function() {
    console.log("id role of user: "+$scope.userSelection.roleUser); // id role of user: undefined
  }
}
```

The best way is clearly the first one, use a named controller.

Comment: I applied the first solution "**use a named controller**" but the list of roles are not displayed  on the  browser. The dexieme solution **Use an object in your ngModel** displays this problem; Can not read property 'roleUser' of undefined.  I do not understand why this problem appears?

Comment: Be sure to affect, your `ListRolesUsers` to vm and not your `$scope` anymore.

Comment: You're right @ Julien, I tested both solution 1/2 and it works. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` create a child scope, so you have to bind to the `$parent`.

Try this `ng-model="$parent.roleUser"` instead of `ng-model="roleUser"`.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.ListRolesUsers = [{"idRole":1,"nomRole":"Admin","authority":"Admin"},
{"idRole":2,"nomRole":"SuperUsers","authority":"SuperUsers"},{"idRole":3,"nomRole":"SimpleUsers","authority":"SimpleUsers"}];

$scope.AddUsers = function() {
    console.log("id role of user: "+$scope.roleUser); // id role of user: undefined
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Role of User*:</label>  
  <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" ng-repeat="roles in ListRolesUsers">
    <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio{{$index}}" name="roleUser" ng-model="$parent.roleUser" value="{{roles.idRole}}" ng-click="AddUsers()">
    <label for="inlineRadio1"> <strong> {{roles.idRole}} // {{roles.nomRole}}</strong> </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is very useful

Comment: @Michel Please mark it as a correct if u thought this is a useful answer so that it will be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem through this code:

**Html**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.roleUser.$touched && myForm.roleUser.$error.required }">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Role of User*:</label>  
  <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" ng-repeat="roles in ListRolesUsers">
    <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio1" name="roleUser" ng-model="userSelection.roleUser" ng-value="roles.idRole">
    <label for="inlineRadio1"> <strong> {{roles.idRole}} // {{roles.nomRole}}</strong> </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('Mainapp', ['ngRoute','file model','ui.bootstrap','ngMessages']);
app.controller("Users"['$scope','fileUpload','$http','$window', function($scope,fileUpload,$http,$window){
  var vm = this;

  $scope.AddUsers = function() {
    console.log("id role of user: "+vm.roleUser); // id role of user: undefined
  }
}
```

Thanks for sir @Julien TASSIN